# my date reads like this - 2002-02-26 02:40 UTC and want to get rid of the '2:40 UTC', how can i do that in python with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

im very new and just trying to learn to clean my data in python using pandas.

i also am trying to learn how to delete other parts of a cell but not all of it, for example -

USPS_MEDIA_CINCINNATI(9102001206932018146748) -- i'd like to just have it read USPS.

any help would be great! thank you!

Comment: `a="USPS_MEDIA_CINCINNATI(9102001206932018146748)"
a[:4]` or split by '_'

Comment: if you want to only keep the first 4 characters of a string in a dataframe then do `df['some_col'] = df['some_col'].str[:4]`

Comment: Each question should be focused on one topic. This was duped, based on the main question shown in the header.

Comment: When asking questions, always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: @ mohsen and chris, thanks for your help!